# Saving Datepicker input to state is causing error

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs

I'm using datepicker in my react app to allow the user select a date that I am then saving in state.

I am getting this warning in the console:

> *backend.js:6 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js
>   Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non
>   RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an
>   upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.*

My code is here:

```
    <div required>
                <DatePicker
                    timeIntervals={15}
                    selected={this.state.userEvent.startDetails}
                    onChange={event =>
                    this.changeField(event, "startDetails")
                    }
                    onBlur={(event) => {this.errorIfSecondTimeIsNotBeforeFirstTime(moment(event.target.value), moment(), 'startDateInPast'); this.setDefaultstopSellingTime(event.target.value)}}
                    showTimeSelect
                    dateFormat="Pp"
                    required
                    placeholderText='Date & Time Event Starts'
                />
                </div>
```

The line of code that is causing the problems is here:

```
selected={this.state.userEvent.startDetails}
```

(when I remove this line the functions I am calling don't cause the error)

This is the function I am calling to change state:

```
  changeField = (e, field) => {
    let userEvent = this.state.userEvent;

        if (field === "startDetails" || field === "endDetails") {
        userEvent[field] = e
    } else {
      userEvent[field] = e.target.value;
    }
    this.setState({ userEvent })
  }
```

I understand that by using e the date is being stored in state in the format `Sat Nov 30 2019 16:30:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)` which is causing the error.

However, if I change the function to use moment(e):

```
  changeField = (e, field) => {
    let userEvent = this.state.userEvent;

        if (field === "startDetails" || field === "endDetails") {
        userEvent[field] = moment(e)
    } else {
      userEvent[field] = e.target.value;
    }
    this.setState({ userEvent })
  }
```

the app crashes and I get the below error:

> *Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value*

What should I do to fix this error

Comment: Is the following link the datepicker component you're using? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment `date` is saved as an `object` but in React you can't render objects directly. You can format the date when rendering it or before setting in `state`. Read more about moment date formatting [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

In your `DatePicker`:

```
<div required>
    <DatePicker
        timeIntervals={15}
        selected={moment(this.state.userEvent.startDetails).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
        onChange={event =>
        this.changeField(event, "startDetails")
        }
        onBlur={(event) => {this.errorIfSecondTimeIsNotBeforeFirstTime(moment(event.target.value), moment(), 'startDateInPast'); this.setDefaultstopSellingTime(event.target.value)}}
        showTimeSelect
        dateFormat="Pp"
        required
        placeholderText='Date & Time Event Starts'
    />
</div>
```

or in `ChangeField` handler

```
changeField = (e, field) => {
    let userEvent = this.state.userEvent;

    if (field === "startDetails" || field === "endDetails") {
        userEvent[field] = moment(e).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    } else {
        userEvent[field] = e.target.value;
    }
    this.setState({ userEvent })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but both are these are causing app to crash